# View Not Animating when triggered

Tags: swiftui

I have this code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
  var body: some View {
    ZStack {
      Rectangle()
      VisualFeedback()
    }
    .gesture(
      TapGesture()
        .onEnded { _ in
          print("animate")
          NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .xxxx,
                                          object: nil,
                                          userInfo: nil)
        })
  }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
    ContentView()
  }
}

extension Notification.Name {
  static let xxxx = Notification.Name("xxxx")
}


struct VisualFeedback : View {
  
  private let totalAnimationTime:Double = 0.4
  
  @State private var scale: CGFloat = 0.2
  @State private var opacity: Double = 0.5
  @State private var triggerFlashAnimation = false
  
  
  init() {
    print("added")
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .xxxx,
                                           object: nil,
                                           queue: OperationQueue.main, using: {[self] _ in
                                            
                                            self.triggerAnimationActions()
                                           })
  }
  
  
  var body: some View {
    ZStack {
      Rectangle()
        .fill(Color.purple.opacity(opacity))
        .scaleEffect(scale)
    }.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
    .onChange(of: scale, perform: { value in
      print("changing values = ", scale, opacity, totalAnimationTime)
    })
  }
  
  
  func triggerAnimationActions() {        
    triggerFlashAnimation = true
    
    print("starting values = ", scale, opacity, totalAnimationTime)
    
    withAnimation(.linear(duration: totalAnimationTime)) {
      scale = 1
    }
    withAnimation(.linear(duration: totalAnimationTime * 0.8)) {
      opacity = 1
    }
    withAnimation(Animation.linear(duration: totalAnimationTime * 0.2)
                    .delay(totalAnimationTime * 0.8)) {
      opacity = 0
    }
    
    
    // reset
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + totalAnimationTime) {
      triggerFlashAnimation = false
      scale = 0.2
      opacity = 0.5
    }
  }
}
```

`VisualFeedback` is a view I want to animate in opacity and scale when I tap the black rectangle. But nothing happens.

NOTE: I need this notification stuff there, because in my app the view will be animated by an arriving notification. I have added this tap gesture to make debugging easy.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your observer on `onReceive` instead of init. Remove addObserver from the VisualFeedback view init.
like this

```
var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        Rectangle()
            .fill(Color.purple.opacity(opacity))
            .scaleEffect(scale)
    }.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
    .onChange(of: scale, perform: { value in
        print("changing values = ", scale, opacity, totalAnimationTime)
    })
    .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default
                .publisher(for: .xxxx)) { (output) in
        self.triggerAnimationActions()
    }
}
```